# Function which derivative at $0$ is $1$ but is not monotonic increasing

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Please, I need help in order to understand the following assumption that I've found in Bartle's book Introduction to Real Analysis page 171. It says:
One might suppose that, if the derivative is strictly positive at a point, then the function is increasing at this point. However, this supposition is false; indeed, the differentiable function defined by

\begin{equation}
  g(x)=\begin{cases}
    x+2x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}), & \text{if $x\neq 0$},\\
    0, & \text{$x=0$}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Ok. So I've got that $g$ is continuous at zero and 
$$g'(0)=1, g'\left(\frac{1}{2n\pi}\right)=-1<0, \text{ and } g'\left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}\right)=3>0.$$ So this function has positive derivative at zero but $g$ is not increasing in any neighborhood of $x = 0$? What am I doing wrong here?

So far what I know is that if a function has positive derivative at a point we can find a neighborhood of that point where the function is increasing.
Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: How does your book define "increasing function at a point"?

Comment: increasing at a point if there is a
neighborhood of the point on which the function is increasing.

Answer (score 6):

Your claim that a function $f$ such that $f'(x) > 0$ is increasing in a neighborhood of $x$ is generally only true for $C^1$ functions (functions that have a continuous derivative). In general it's not true. Indeed, try to prove it, and you'll see that you need $f'$ to be positive in a whole neighborhood of $x$, not just at $x$ (proofs can use the mean value theorem, for example).

Here the function can be increasing in a neighborhood of $0$, because if it were the derivative would be positive in a neighborhood of $0$ (again, MVT), but $g'(\frac{1}{2n\pi}) < 0$ so any neighborhood of zero contains points where the derivative is negative.

Comment: But derivative is 3>0 at zero, doesn´t it means that in a neighborhood of zero (f(x)-f(0))/(x-0)=f(x)/x >0. So if x>0 then f(x)-f(0)=x.f(x)/x > 0.? What's wrong?

Comment: Yes, $f(x)$ is bigger than $f(0)$ in some $(0,\epsilon)$ and smaller than $f(0)$ in some $(-\epsilon, 0)$. It doesn't mean the function is locally increasing. For that you would need $x < y \implies f(x) < f(y)$ for **all** $x,y \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, not just when one of the two is zero.